# Can I follow recipes for bread-machine breads without bread machine?

Tags: equipment, bread

I was browsing a [recipe website](http://allrecipes.com/recipes/bread/bread-machine/main.aspx) to get some recipes for breads. There is a section marked with bread-machine breads.I am very new to bread making and after some search it seems that the machine is used for baking and kneading. So will it be possible for me to follow the recipes with a normal oven?

Comment: To be clear, are you wanting to make a bread recipe that is listed for a bread maker but you do not have a bread-making machine?

Comment: Exactly and before I go for one I want to be more experience on bread making

Comment: I have a bread machine and you can have it. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bread machine recipe books come with conversion instructions to make the bread traditionally.  Here is a link to a site that will do the same:

http://breaddaily.tripod.com/recipeconversion.htm

Best of luck with your bread making!

Answer (score 6):

You can probably use the same recipes, but... hand kneading is more difficult than letting the machine do it. The wet dough can be very sticky. So, if the recipe has a high hydration (water:flour) you may want to reduce the water in the recipe.

So, if the recipe calls for 250ml water:500g flour, this is 50% hydration, and you should be able to knead that. But 300ml water, or 60% hydration is much harder...

It also depends on the flour you have, but try to be conservative about the water until you get a feel for it.

Comment: I wish SE would let us mark more than 1 reply as answer

Comment: @Tanmoy, No worries, you pick the best there is, or the one that suits you best, and you can always edit answers to make them more comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

I use my bread machine just for the kneading and first rise, and then bake in the oven.  The bread nachine recipe won't give any baking directions, and the loaf size may not be quite what you want, but other than that, I've found the recipes completely interchangable.  Use both bread machine and non-bread machine recipes in the bread machine (make sure you use an appropriate size), and use both as just bread by hand too.